# vagrant 1.0.3 not creating device for host only network debian 6

Tags: debian, vagrant

I have a hostonly network created with the following line in my Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.network :hostonly, "10.1.1.15"
```

I can see that it sets up the /etc/network/interfaces file

```
#VAGRANT-BEGIN
# The contents below are automatically generated by Vagrant. Do not modify.
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
      address 10.1.1.15
      netmask 255.255.255.0
#VAGRANT-END
```

However, when I run ifconfig I only see an eth0 and a lo device. Why is vagrant not setting up a device for eth1? What is the solution to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, after some more digging I found a solution.

In case it matters, here are some details about my environment:

```
Ubuntu 12.10
Vagrant 1.0.3 install from the Ubuntu repos using apt-get
Virtualbox 4.1.24 downloaded from the virtualbox website
```

As far as I can tell, the boxes I've used and had this problem with (precise32 from vagrantup.com as well as a squeeze 64 box from vagrantbox.es) are being shipped with some rules set up in the **/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules** file. These are normally updated during every boot, but for some reason this is not happening. This causes a device such as eth1--which is commonly used for setting up hostonly networking in vagrant--to never be set up and the OS does not think it's configured.

You can remove the pertaining rules in the file or just remove the file. Then do a reboot and the problem should be fixed. Every time you do a **vagrant destroy** or create a new vagrant VM you will have to do this. However, thanks to simonmcc on the #vagrant freenode channel for pointing out a more permanent fix.

You can delete that file without rebooting, then do a vagrant package to repackage the box this way. Otherwise, create your own box from scratch (using veewee or not) and make sure this file is set up correctly then package it.